# Form validation div sometimes doesn't show up, even though requirements are met

Tags: magento-1.9, validation

I have added length validation to my address field.
 
Validation gets updated with a keypress:

```
$('street_1').on('keyup', function(e){
        Validation.validate($('street_1'))
    });
```

Validation has two states: `validation-passed`, where the error `div` is `opacity: 0; display: none`:[image]

And `validation-failed`, when it displays the error:
[image]

**BUT**, often if I type past the limit, it will go in `validation-failed`, but error `div` will still be `display: none`...[image]Why is this happening?

Perhaps is something to do with the "fading" effect?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it had something to do with the fading effect not finishing before the next update is called so I added a 150ms delay which is not noticeable and fixes the issue!

```
  $('street_1').on('keyup', function(e){
            setTimeout(function(){
            Validation.validate($('street_1'));
          },150); 
    });
```